# pipe command output to html with files as links (bash)

Tags: html, bash, sed

Some command I use ([task-spooler](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/)) produces text in table format and with some fields as filenames

I'd like to pipe the output of that command to generate a HTML file, s.t. I can click on the filename in the browser, and it would open in a new browser tab.

I am guessing, I should have some way to detect filenames and wrap them as `<a href="file://x/y/z.txt">file://x/y/z.txt</a>`. Is there an easy way to make it from the bash command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I piped to a python script:

to_html.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Convert a piped in text input to html, while replacing file/path names with URLs
"""
import sys
import os
import re

def path_to_html_link(field):
    field = field.group()
    if os.path.isfile(field) or os.path.isdir(field):
        return """<a href="file://{0}"  target="_blank">{0}  </a>""".format(field)

    else:
        return field

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if not line: break  # EOF

        line = re.sub('/[^\s]*', path_to_html_link, line)
        line = '<p><tt>' + line + '</tt></p>'
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

And then called

```
chmod +x to_html.py
ts | to_html.py > tmp.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sed`. The regexp here is very simple and will likely require tweaking depending on your particular data.

```
~ $ echo -e 'http://google.com/asdf says hello\nthis is another url here: https://example.com/' | \
    sed -E 's#(http[^ ]+)#<a href="\1">\1</a>#g'
<a href="http://google.com/asdf">http://google.com/asdf</a> says hello
this is another url here: <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a>
~ $
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I don't have URL links. Just filenames. sed should somehow detected which are filenames. If it helps, I can assume a filename starts with `/`

Answer (score 0):

like:

```
#!/bin/bash

make_page() {
    echo "<html><body><ul>"
    got=
    while read -r id state file etc
    do
        [[ -f "$file" ]] && {
        printf "<li><a href="file://%s"><%s></a></li>\n" "$file" "$file";
        got=1;
        }
    done < <(sed 1d)    #skip header
    [[ -z "$got" ]] && echo '<li>No any file</li>'
    echo "</ul</body></html>"
}
[[ "$1" ]] && [[ ! -f "$1" ]] && { echo "no file $1" >&2; exit 1; }
[[ "$1" ]] && exec 3<"$1" || exec 3<&0
make_page <&3
```

save it to `tspage.sh` and use as `tspage.sh filename` or `tspage.sh < filename`